# Varying length of indices within a structure in C

Tags: c, struct

Is it possible to have varying length of indices for elements within a structure. Here is the code that I intend to write-

```
struct sub_list 
{
 int c[index_1];
 int d[index_1];
 int e[index_1];
}

struct main_list
{
int a;
int b;
struct sub_list slist[index_2];
}

struct main_list mlist[2];
```

Is it possible to have one set of index lengths for index_1 and index_2 for mlist[1] and another for mlist[2]? If so, how can it be done? (Through #defines?)

Comment: No, but you can have one _flexible struct member_.

Comment: @user3121023- I'm kinda new to C programming and not very comfortable with malloc and pointers. If possible, could you modify the code/insert the lines of code to the one that I posted? That would be of great help!